# Guess what I've been looking at all day

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm part of life including you,
>
> A word of many meanings true,
>
> In rows and columns hundreds and tens,
>
> We're oft caged like so many hens.

What are we?

Answer (score 14):

You are

> cells

I'm part of life including you

> living organisms consist of cells

A word of many meanings true

> storm cell, battery cell, etc.

In rows and columns hundreds and tens

> cells of a spreadsheet

We're oft caged like so many hens.

> prison cell

Comment: Yeah...  not exactly a real brain scrambler that one.  You'll have to wait 8 min before I can accept.  And the last line was also a reference to 'battery' hens.